# Unexpected symbol although column names are formatted correctly

Tags: r, variables, error-handling, names

I changed the names of the columns to be compatible with R and attempted running a linear model. I received this error. I also get this error when attempting to run a mixed effects model. What did I do wrong?

Thanks.

> linearModel = lm(Cost.Per.Click ~ 7.Day.Conversion.Rate, data=amazonData)

> Error: unexpected symbol in "linearModel = lm(Cost.Per.Click ~ 7.Day.Conversion.Rate"

Answer (score 1):

The name of your variable is [non-syntatic](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html#non-syntactic), because it starts with a digit. Try either renaming the variable or quoting it with back ticks

```
linearModel = lm(Cost.Per.Click ~ `7.Day.Conversion.Rate`, data=amazonData)
```

to rename all column names to syntactical names you can use

```
names(df) <- make.names(names(df))
```

among many other options.

Comment: great to hear... you may accept the answer as solved :)